# What does my team mate need to have installed in order to join my VS2019 live share session?

Tags: visual-studio

I am keen to try live share with a remote team mate. Yesterday I was nagging one to install VS2019.

Now I am wondering whether that actually needs to happen.

I see from [this youtube at 1.35](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QXwSg9-2qQ) that a user running VSCode with an extension installed can join a session.

At 2:17 it explains that Live Share needs to be installed on my team mate's machine.  What is the minimum needed to install Live Share?

[Update]
I cant find how to install for VS2017 at [the live share link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/)

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/quickstart/share) you can live share with yourself ;)

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/use-cases

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/connectivity

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/quickstart/join

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [the live share extension needs to be present](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/quickstart/join)
This will be true if the guest has Visual Studio Code (1.22.0+)  or VS2019 or VS2017 15.6 or higher